# Can't update bash. Couldn't resolve proxy : proxyaddress

Tags: bash, proxy, git, windows-registry

This problem occured while trying to update bash. I'm using Win10 and I remember changing a field (in the registry files?) to proxyaddress for some reason I don't know.

I have followed some guidelines from the internet like the command :git config --global --unset http.proxy but doesn't work also the echo http_proxy, echo https_proxy, etc doesn't show anything. 
I also went to the registry edit under the *\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings* path. The proxy enable is set to 0, but I can't find the fields ProxyServer or ProxyOverride in there.

I just can't find where this field, where the value proxyaddress is set, is located so I can reset it.

Comment: Did you try searching the Registry? This is a key reason why modifying the registry should only be done very carefully.

Comment: @music2myear I did as I mentioned. The problem is that I can't locate (in the registry) the field which I've changed to "proxyaddress" and the fields under the path I've written take values not strings. The only field there that could take a string value is ProxyAddress and it's missing. On the other hand what I;m searching for might not be there (in the registry). So what it all comes down to is to find the path from where the bash finds the error "couldn't resolve proxy" but I don't know how I can trace that.

Comment: It will be difficult to find something you cannot find yourself. We didn't make the change, and there are many fields in the registry with similar names.